# File is corruping when sent from client to server

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have been working with wifi direct where I create server and client conditionally, and when I send the file from client to server the file is corrupting. I have used `inputstream.copyTo(outputstream)` it's working perfectly, I don't know whats wrong with my code.

**CLIENT**

```
var len = 0
val buf = ByteArray(1248)
//                    inputstreamFile!!.copyTo(objectoutPutStream)
while (inputstreamFile!!.read(buf).also {size-> len = size } != -1) {
    Log.i("INFO",buf.toString())
    objectoutPutStream.write(buf, 0, len);
    objectoutPutStream.flush();
    Progress.wrote = Progress.wrote + len
    Log.i("INFO",Progress.wrote.toString())
    context.runOnUiThread{
        context.increaseProgress()
    }
```

**SERVER**

```
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(fileCreate)
    var len = 0
    val byteArray = ByteArray(1248)
    while (inputStream.read(byteArray).also { it -> len = it } != -1){
        outputStream.write(byteArray)
        MainProgress.FileProgress = MainProgress.FileProgress + len
        outputStream.flush()
        context.runOnUiThread {
            context.setProgress()
        }
    }
//                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
    MainProgress.FileProgress = 0
    outputStream.close()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAxYj.jpg

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error in terminal, https://imgur.com/Wu29qi7 <=  the image file become's weird

Comment: Are you sending an image file then ?

Comment: when i use **copyTo** method its working perfectly bro, i can send any files without problem

Comment: pastebin :  https://pastebin.com/54epdyb1

Comment: Sorry then i dont understand the question.